# How to use lldb to debug the segmentation fault

Tags: c, lldb

I got this exception by running LLDB for my program.

However, the exception didn't give me any concrete clues for finding the root cause.

Of course, based on experience, I might access the memory not correctly.

Any idea to find the root cause by LLDB? Thanks

```
continue to play (y/n)? y
Process 30020 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x24b72, 0x00007fff893c8365 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strncmp + 325, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x79)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff893c8365 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strncmp + 325
libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strncmp:
->  0x7fff893c8365 <+325>: movzbq (%rsi,%rcx), %r8
    0x7fff893c836a <+330>: subq   %r8, %rax
    0x7fff893c836d <+333>: jne    0x7fff893c837d            ; <+349>
    0x7fff893c836f <+335>: testq  %r8, %r8
(lldb)
error: No auto repeat.
```

## code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>

const int USER_INPUT_SIZE_EACH_LINE = 999;

void draw_middle_lines(char *middle_line, int width) {
    printf("%s", middle_line);
    for (int i = 2; i < width; i++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%s\n", middle_line);
}

void draw_bound_line(char *bound_char, int width) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        printf("%s", bound_char);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void clearNewline(char *line, int max_len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max_len; i++) {
        if (line[i] == '\n') {
            line[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
}

char **ask_user_preference() {
    const int NUM_OF_PROMPTS = 4;
    char *prompt[] = {
            "please input height:",
            "please input width:",
            "please input horizontal char:",
            "please input vertical char:",
    };
    char **preference;
    preference = malloc(NUM_OF_PROMPTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PROMPTS; i++) {
        preference[i] = malloc(USER_INPUT_SIZE_EACH_LINE);
        memset(preference[i], 0, sizeof(char) * USER_INPUT_SIZE_EACH_LINE);
        printf("%s", prompt[i]);
        fgets(preference[i], USER_INPUT_SIZE_EACH_LINE, stdin);
        clearNewline(preference[i], USER_INPUT_SIZE_EACH_LINE);
    }
    return preference;
}

void draw(int w, int h, char *bound_char, char *middle_char) {
    draw_bound_line(bound_char, w);
    for (int i = 2; i < h; i++) {
        draw_middle_lines(middle_char, w);
    }
    draw_bound_line(bound_char, w);
}

void clr_input_buffer() {
    for (;;) {
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;
    }

}

int main() {
    char *cont;
    do {
        char **pref = ask_user_preference();
        int height = atoi(pref[0]);
        int width = atoi(pref[1]);
        char *bound_char = pref[2];
        char *middle_char = pref[3];
        draw(width, height, bound_char, middle_char);
        printf("continue to play (y/n)? ");
        fgets(cont, 10, stdin);
        if (strncmp(cont, 'y', 1) != 0) {
            break;
        }
    } while (1);
    printf("BYE BYE~");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function call

```
strncmp(cont, 'y', 1)
```

will likely cause a segfault, because `'y'` is a character value passed as a memory location. I suggest

```
strncmp(cont, "y", 1)
```

although I am unsure of the sense of of your comparison. Anyway I suggest this would be better

```
toupper(cont[0]) == 'Y'
```

and I leave the sense of the comparison to you. Finally please enable all compiler warnings which would have caught this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this good point. the segementation issue was fixed. however, is there anyway to make this issue more likely to be found? it seems you're using your experience to fix it instead of the help of debugger or exception message^^

Comment: The compiler does issue a warning.

Comment: In fact the MSVC compiler issues *two* warnings: one about parameter type, and one about level of indirection.

Comment: This answer still does not answer the original question of how to debug this error with lldb...

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś this answer is that you can catch the error way before the debugger, by looking at the compiler output. You should not even be running code that was issued with warnings. It is trivial to catch this error.